SocketIO connection disconnects when sending data about 1mb over it through nginx proxy_pass
I've socketio connection in python flask that I can connect to it directly and send data over it without any problem, but when I use nginx as webserver and reverse_proxy and pass socketio connection via it, the connection disconnects when I send large data, about 1MB.
`
I used many nginx options, such as:
        location /socket.io { 
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
        client_body_buffer_size 100M;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_buffers 8 5M;
        proxy_buffer_size 5M;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout 300s;
        proxy_buffering off;  # Disable buffering for WebSocket

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

`
I used nginx in docker container.
How can I resolve this issue?


Have you tried
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

@KhanAsfiReza Yes, tried, nothing changed.

Check the Nginx logs
/var/log/nginx/error.log and /var/log/nginx/access.log
It can provide clues about whether the connection is being dropped due to buffer limits, timeouts, or another reason.
Because as your Nginx Configuration Block is good for sending 1M data
you can try to increase the time, if it works
proxy_read_timeout 700s;
proxy_send_timeout 700s;

